# Formatting headers for SQL statements

Tags: c#, sql, csv, datatable

I have a table of baseball stats in a CSV file which I query as,

```
SELECT 
    birthState, COUNT(playerId) 
FROM 
    [Master.csv] 
GROUP BY 
    birthState 
ORDER BY 
    COUNT(birthState) DESC
```

The result is displayed as,

```
birthState  Expr1001
--------------------
   CA       2160
   PA       1417
   NY       1207
   IL       1054
```

I have some (imperfect) logic to iterate over the column names in the resulting `DataTable` (I'm using C#) to fill in the headers above.

Is there a way to represent the header of the second column as `COUNT(playerId)` instead of `Expr1001`?

Thanks.

Comment: use alias SELECT birthState, COUNT(playerId) Expr1001

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the "as" (or alias) command this will return the computed column with a specified header:

```
SELECT birthState, COUNT(playerId) as NumberOfPlayers
FROM [Master.csv] GROUP BY birthState ORDER BY COUNT(birthState) DESC
```

I'm not sure if you can label the header "Count(playerid)" this way, but using square brackets around the name:

```
SELECT birthState, COUNT(playerId) as [Count(playerid)]
FROM [Master.csv] GROUP BY birthState ORDER BY COUNT(birthState) DESC
```

should treat the text as just text rather than a command.